# tensorflow-hub: Python import error when file is in a specific folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

So I ran into this super strange issue. I am trying to run the example code of tensorflow-hub given on this webpage: https://www.tensorflow.org/hub
(I removed both !pip statements)

I want to use a small piece of python code for the machine learning stuff within my application which is otherwise written in go. However when I execute the example code in the project directory of my application it gives an import error.

So when I create a file tf-hub.py in ~/ and execute it, it runs, prints some warnings and the result:

```sh
$python3 tf-hub.py
WARNING: Logging before flag parsing goes to stderr.
W0621 10:35:21.367268 140170246772224 deprecation_wrapper.py:118] From tf-hub.py:4: The name tf.enable_eager_execution is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution instead.

2019-06-21 10:35:21.407732: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-06-21 10:35:21.427007: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2793545000 Hz
2019-06-21 10:35:21.428085: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x563567fc7a90 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-06-21 10:35:21.428143: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-06-21 10:35:21.505990: W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1541] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
2019-06-21 10:35:21.513612: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:81] Allocation of 498570752 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2019-06-21 10:35:22.109499: W tensorflow/core/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:81] Allocation of 498570752 exceeds 10% of system memory.
(3, 128)
```

However when I copy the same file to the project folder of the go project I get the following import error:

```sh
$ python3 go/src/MyProject/tagger/imageClassifier/tf-hub.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/tf_v1.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.compat.v1 import *  # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'; 'tensorflow' is not a package

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "go/src/EmbeddingImageTagger/tagger/imageClassifier/tf-hub.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/***/go/src/EmbeddingImageTagger/tagger/imageClassifier/tensorflow.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow_hub as hub
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow_hub.estimator import LatestModuleExporter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/estimator.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow_hub import tf_utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/tf_utils.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow_hub import tf_v1
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/tf_v1.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorflow import add_to_collection
ImportError: cannot import name 'add_to_collection' from 'tensorflow' (/home/***/go/src/MyProject/tagger/imageClassifier/tensorflow.py)
```

I have to use tf-nightly, otherwise I run into this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/289

I am using:

- Fedora 29 64-bit
- Python 3.7.2
- tf-nightly 1.14.1.dev20190621
- tensorflow-hub 0.4.0

Any ideas what could cause this weird behavior that the file runs in one directory, but not in another? I also tried to run both from the same terminal. Still it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my. So I found the culprit after I cleaned up the debug stuff and moved my development to my home folder.

The problem was that I had a python file called `tensorflow.py` because it was supposed to contain a classifier solution with tensorflow. Well it seems that this confuses python and python now imports this file when importing tensorflow.

I had to just rename the file and now it works.